# Dictionary object with Observable: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

```
 isEnabledDeleteCourtChanged$: { [courtId: string]: Observable<boolean> };

 private isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$: { [courtId: string]: BehaviorSubject<boolean> };

 private initialize(): void {

  this.isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$= new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // here has problem
  this.isEnabledDeleteCourtChanged$ = this.isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$.asObservable(); // here has problem
}

 setIsEnabledDeleteCourt(courtId: string, isEnabled: boolean): void {

    this.isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$[courtId].next(isEnabled); // here has problem
}
```

The above code is not working. It says `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`. So can you tell me how to construct the Dictionary object with Observable properly? Initializing is also not working? i.e. `initialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we cannot declare/init it without `courtId`. So this works for me.

*service.ts*

```
isEnabledRevertToGroupChanged$: { [courtId: string]: Observable<boolean> } = {};

private isEnabledRevertToGroupSubject$: { [courtId: string]: BehaviorSubject<boolean> } = {};

setIsEnabledDeleteCourt(courtId: string, isEnabled: boolean): void {

        this.isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$[courtId] = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

        this.isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$[courtId].next(isEnabled);

        this.isEnabledDeleteCourtChanged$[courtId] = this.isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$[courtId].asObservable();
    }
```

*html*

```
 <ion-col *ngIf="queueDataService?.isEnabledDeleteCourtChanged$[queue?.qId] | async">
 </ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the object it is `isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$` do you really want that $ on the end of it - is there any need for the $? When setting it you have `isEnabledDeleteCourtSubject$=` there is no space - maybe the undefined issue?